# Save rapidsms data in database

Tags: python, django

I installed Django and rapidsms in local machine and now i want to save incoming message in databse. The data received as a string in rapidsms handler and how it can split and save to fields of a table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here https://github.com/unicefuganda/rapidsms-httprouter/blob/master/rapidsms_httprouter/models.py is an example where there is defined a simple Message Model and all associated fields ( text, connection,...). See if it can inspire you.